# reading an audio file to save the values on a text file in Android

Tags: android, matlab, audio

I am trying to develop a simple code that reads data from an audio file saved in the SD card. For instance let's say an audio file "a.wav", after that I would like to save the data on a text file inside the phone. The thing I am looking for is something exactly the same as the function "readwav" in MATLAB in which I could read the audio file and then save the values on a text file.How could I achieve this in android? I searched for many codes however I could not find something simple.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do mean by 'save data to a text file'? PCM byte values? Does it have to decode from compressed files or just .wav?

Comment: Actually I am not very knowledgeable in programing terms such as PCM byte values .. The output am expecting is something like integers or double numbers.. and no I only want the code to read the data from .Wav file.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link-http://vimeo.com/27642353.It says

```
This is a Processing Tutorial about:
How to save audio data to text files...
... and load this text file, prepare and display it.
This way you are able to visualize music, but your sketch doesn't have to run in realtime (e. g. complex visualizations, render your visualization). Most (or every?) Processing library doesn't support that.
Sorry for the bad and slow typing (misspellings, senseless word order). It's really tough for me to phrase, to type and think and the same time.
Code: 
openprocessing.org/visuals/?visualID=33855
Music:
CocoRosie - The moon asked the crow
```